# Weka values too high

Tags: csv, dataset, weka

I am trying to preprocess the data that I currently have on Weka. However, I tried many filters but no matter what I keep on getting the same exact error which is, "Too many values to display."

[image: This is an image of the error I have I don't know if you guys can see the image or not.]

What should I do?

I try many filters, but it kept on giving me the exact same error message on the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You get the **Too many values to display** message when the selected nominal attribute has more labels than the panel is wide in pixels.

Based on your screenshot, you seem to have selected the **ID** attribute. Usually, ID attributes uniquely identify a single row in a dataset. A histogram computed for such an attribute is usually useless, as they tend to be evenly distributed (1 label = 1 row).